# Why won't my div stay fixed on the screen?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a popup that should be fixed on the screen but for some reason it will not work. Here is the code...

Html.

```
<div id='hear-about-us-div' style='display:block'>
<h2 id='hdyhau-header'>How did you hear about us?</h2>
<form name='hear-about-us-form'>

  <label>Facebook</label>
  <input type='checkbox' name='facebook' />
  <label>Instagram</label>
  <input type='checkbox' name='instagram'/>
  <label>Friends or family</label>
  <input type='checkbox' name='friendsOrFamily'/>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type='checkbox' name='email'/>
  <label>Other</label>
  <input type='checkbox' name='other'/>

  <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS.

```
 #hear-about-us-div {
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   left: 25%;
   height: 250px;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #EB8364;
   z-index: 101;
 }
```

Comment: If it is not fixed already, then what is it doing?

Comment: Did you forget to close your div with </div> ?

Comment: Did not forget div. And it is scrolling with rest of the page.

Comment: Where are you closing your div?

Comment: try adding top:10px in your css of whatever top offset you want.

Comment: The issue is probably caused by something else in your application. I've put your code in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXZeNO and your `#hear-about-us-div` is fixed.

Comment: If you want a useful answer to your problem, you absolutely have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).